# Stop account's activities for 24 hours

Tags: 7, users

How can I temporarily ban an email address for up to one month?

I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: You're asking 4 questions at the same time, without any information about context and requirements. Please elaborate and perhaps consider splitting this question into separate questions.

Comment: only one question plz answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Troll](http://drupal.org/project/troll) module, which seems to do what you need; it isn't looked after.
For other options you also have the [Cave your trolls](http://drupal.org/project/cave) module, which hides user's posts from anyone other than themselves, or the [Misery](http://drupal.org/project/misery) module, which makes the site unusable for certain users.

Comment: no one is use full for me and all are not in stable condition :(

Answer (score 0):

Block the user.

1 month later, come back and unblock the user.

OR post some details about what you're specifically looking to accomplish.

Comment: after 1 month user automatically unblock like cron jobs

Comment: 1 month is more than 24 hours, isn't it?